# Is it possible to create a folder on the Alfresco site by using OpenCMIS API?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, alfresco-webscripts, opencmis

I have the [Presentation Web Script](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/ws-types-presentation.html) (`script A`) and the [Data Web Script](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/ws-types-data.html) (`script B`).

In the `script A` I build the dialog that interacts with the `script B`.

[image]

Here I am forming some path where the some file will be uploaded (`group`, `year` and `number` parameters define this path):

```
...
var submitHandler = function() {
    var dataWebScriptUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + 
        window.location.host + "/alfresco/s/ms-ws/script-b?guest=true";

    var yearCombo = document.getElementById("year");
    var year = yearCombo.options[yearCombo.selectedIndex].value;

    var groupCombo = document.getElementById("group");
    var group = groupCombo.options[groupCombo.selectedIndex].value;

    var numberCombo = document.getElementById("number");
    var number = numberCombo.value;

    var uploadedFile = document.getElementById("uploadedFile");
    var file = uploadedFile.files[0];

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("year", year);
    formData.append("group", group);
    formData.append("number", number);
    formData.append("uploadedFile", file);      

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", dataWebScriptUrl);
    xhr.send(formData);
};
...
```

In `script B`, I'm using the [Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS API](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) to create a path in the [CMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services)-compatible Alfresco repository:

```
public class CustomFileUploader extends DeclarativeWebScript implements OpenCmisConfig {
    ...
    private void retrievePostRequestParams(WebScriptRequest req) {
        String groupName = null, year = null, number = null;

        FormData formData = (FormData) req.parseContent();
        FormData.FormField[] fields = formData.getFields();
        for(FormData.FormField field : fields) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            String fieldValue = field.getValue();

            if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("group")) {
                if(fieldValue.equalsIgnoreCase("services")) {
                    groupName = "Услуги";
                ...                         
        }

        firstLevelFolderName = "/" + groupName;
        secondLevelFolderName = groupName + " " + year; 
        thirdLevelFolderName = number;
    }

    ...

    Folder firstLevelFolder = 
                createFolderIfNotExists(cmisSession, docLibFolder, firstLevelFolderName);

    ...

    private Folder createFolderIfNotExists(Session cmisSession, 
            Folder parentFolder, String folderName) {
        Folder subFolder = null;
        for(CmisObject child : parentFolder.getChildren()) {
            if(folderName.equalsIgnoreCase(child.getName())) {
                subFolder = (Folder) child;
            }
        }

        if(subFolder == null) {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put("cmis:objectTypeId", "cmis:folder");
            props.put("cmis:name", folderName);

            subFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(props);
        }
        return subFolder; 
    }

    private Folder getDocLibFolder(Session cmisSession, String siteName) {
        String path = "/Sites/" + siteName + "/documentLibrary";
        return (Folder) cmisSession.getObjectByPath(path);
    }

    private Session getCmisSession() {
        SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        Map<String, String> conf = new HashMap<>();

        // http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom
        conf.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, ATOMPUB_URL);
        conf.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
        conf.put(SessionParameter.USER, USER_NAME);
        conf.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, PASSWORD);

        // "org.alfresco.cmis.client.impl.AlfrescoObjectFactoryImpl"
        conf.put(SessionParameter.OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS, OBJECT_FACTORY_CLASS);
        conf.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, "-default-");

        Session session = factory.createSession(conf);

        return session;
    }

    ...
```

It's all works well... But I need to create the directory structure on a specific site, e.g. "contracts-site", here:

```
/site/contracts-site/documentlibrary
```

When I specifying the following:

```
/Sites/contracts-site/documentLibrary/Услуги
/Sites/contracts-site/Услуги
/site/contracts-site/documentlibrary/Услуги
```

I get the following exception (depending on the path):

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException: Object not found: /Sites/contracts-site/Услуги
```

When I specifying the following:

```
"/Услуги"
```

Everything works, but the directory structure is created outside the site...

How to create a folder on the Alfresco site by using OpenCMIS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just accidentally found the solution. Works perfectly if specify the following path:

```
// locate the document library
String path = "/Сайты/contracts-site/documentLibrary";
```

Ie, `"Сайты"` instead of `"Sites"`... (Cyrillic alphabet)

I'm using `ru_RU` locale and `UTF-8` encoding. Then [this example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Alfresco-One-5x-Developers-Guide/blob/master/Chapter05/someco-client-extensions-project-ch5/cmis/src/main/java/com/someco/CmisTest.java) also works.

Answer (score 1):

Arn't you missing `/company_home/` ?

This would lead to

```
/company_home/Sites/contracts-site/documentLibrary/Услуги
```

Comment: Sorry then for not been useful.